# Facebook likes counter mechanism

Tags: facebook-like

I have a question. Let say brand A have FB page and a blog. If i copy a blog entry URL and share it in the FB page ( the blog also installed with FB like plugin). When a visitor like the post in FB, does the like counter will be same with the like counter in the blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you already have the answer.

FB Page - User like page. will increase the Like on the page.
Blog - User like post. will not increase like on the fb page.

Comment: I am just not certain with my answer. A client make me confuse when they mentioned sharing the same blog post, but i think with your answer now i am confirmed with my answer. By the way, its not liking the Page, its like a post in the FB page.